# Identify this carousel Slider

Tags: wordpress, carousel, jslider

I'm trying to figure out what slider this is, can anybody help me identify what it is: 
http://clbarchitects.com/projects/rcr/.

I'm looking for something that can show both portrait and landscape images without losing any aspect of the images in full browser mode..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) Seems they are using a custom made but I found this free plugin which also based on Slick Slider https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-slick-slider-and-image-carousel/